# Inserting not calculated Id in table transact SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure where I receive data as JSON from a API in C#. I insert the data into two tables like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.ServiceRequestHeader(SubscriptionId, CustomerAccountId, ModifiedBy)
OUTPUT Inserted.ServiceRequestHeaderId INTO @TempT
    SELECT
        SubscriptionId,
        CustomerAccountId,
        ModifiedBy
    FROM
        OpenJson(@JsonServiceRequest)
        WITH 
           (SubscriptionId TinyInt,
            CustomerAccountId Int)

SELECT @TempId = Id FROM @TempT   

INSERT INTO dbo.ServiceRequest(ServiceRequestId, ServiceRequestHeaderId, SubscriptionId)
    SELECT
        @TempId, -- <= Here I need to modify the serviceRequestHeaderId
        @TempId,
        SubscriptionId
    FROM
        OpenJson(@JsonServiceRequest, '$.ServiceRequest')
        WITH (SubscriptionId TinyInt,
             ...)
```

The thing is that the `serviceRequestId` is not a calculated field and it's a special case that depends on `ServiceRequestHeaderId`.

Example:

- If `ServiceRequestHeaderId = 1000` the `ServiceRequestId` would be 1000 001, 1000 002... N...

This is where I can't come with a way to do it

Comment: This `Select @TempId = Id From @TempT` implies you only ever insert a single service request header in one go? Is that the case?

Comment: Yes just One service request header, but multiple Service Requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate servicerequestids as given below. I am using FORMAT function with `000` for padding with 0 till 3 digits. If you want four digits, use `0000`.

```sql
SELECT @TempId = Id FROM @TempT   

INSERT INTO dbo.ServiceRequest(ServiceRequestId, ServiceRequestHeaderId, SubscriptionId)
    SELECT
        CONCAT(@TempId,FORMAT(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT null)),'000')) AS ServiceRequestId, -- <= Here I need to modify the serviceRequestHeaderId
        @TempId,
        SubscriptionId
    FROM
        OpenJson(@JsonServiceRequest, '$.ServiceRequest')
        WITH (SubscriptionId TinyInt,
             ...)
```

You will get something like below:

```
+------------------+
| ServiceRequestId |
+------------------+
|          1000001 |
|          1000002 |
|          1000003 |
+------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a CTE to calculate a row number per request and then build the id from it e.g.

```
with MyCTE as (
  select
    SubscriptionId
    -- Order by whatever makes business sense to you
    , row_number() over (order by SubscriptionId) rn
  from openjson(@JsonServiceRequest, '$.ServiceRequest')
  with (
    SubscriptionId tinyint,
    ...
  )
)
insert into dbo.ServiceRequest (ServiceRequestId, ServiceRequestHeaderId, SubscriptionId)
  -- Put whatever logic you like here to calculate a row number based id
  select convert(varchar(4),@TempId) + ' ' + case when rn >= 100 then convert(varchar(3),rn) when rn > 10 then '0' + convert(varchar(2),rn) else '00' + convert(varchar(1),rn) end
    , @TempId, SubscriptionId
  from MyCTE;
```